# During ng-show the text is not appearing on ui

Tags: html, angularjs

During "ng-show" the text is not appearing on gui. Help me to say what is wrong in the code.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCntrl">
        <form name="nishant" ng-submit="submit()">
            <div>
                Name : <input type="text" name="name" ng-minlenght="5"
                    required="required"> <span
                    ng-show="nishant.name.$error.minlength">required12</span>
            </div>
            <button name="button" type="submit">SUbmit</button>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
            app.controller("myCntrl", function($scope) {
                alert("nishant");

                $scope.submit = function() {
                    alert("in the submit");
                }
            });
        </script>
</div>
```

Please see why ng-show is not appearing in the screen. If i am removing my controller it is appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Final Code for showing messages using `ng-show`.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

**Answer:**

You need to add a `ng-model` for using the form validators (`nishant.name.$error.minlength`). Also you have misspelt `ng-minlength`.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
  //alert("nishant");

  $scope.submit = function() {
    alert("in the submit");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
  <form name="nishant" ng-submit="submit()">
    <div>
      Name :
      <input type="text" name="name" ng-minlength="5" required="required" ng-model="name"> <span ng-show="nishant.name.$error.minlength">required12</span>
    </div>
    <button name="button" type="submit">SUbmit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: no even after adding ng-model also i am not getting the ng-show msgs over my screen.Kindly, help.

Comment: @NishantSingh did you correct the `ng-minlength` can you provide a JSFiddle with the issue?

Comment: Ya i coorected that also, and if i am adding controller then only it is not appearing.What is JSFiddle i don't know.

Comment: @NishantSingh Try to replicate the issue here [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L15h54kz/) and share it to me!!!! I think you need to register!

Comment: I am not able to replicate since i don't know why the controllers are not getting invoked there.

Comment: @NishantSingh Are you getting any errors in the console (F12)?

Comment: No, i don't know why but if am removing the controller i am getting the msg fine.

Comment: @NishantSingh if you are using `$scope.nishant` anywhere in the controller, comment that out and try!!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Nishant123456/czooqz88/#&togetherjs=068aJvHqKt please go to this and see the issue.

Comment: @NishantSingh The same code I gave is there inside the link, share the controller code inside!

Comment: kindly see and suggest some somethimg.

Comment: @NishantSingh Updated my answer with the final code!